# Sorting Arraylist Java

Tags: sorting, arraylist

I have a txt file I put into an array. The data in the txt file has data in the format as:

```
Order #     Date     Name     City     State    Zip Code    Transaction Amount
```

across a row with each item representing a column.

Then there is a 1000 more rows that have these filled in with answers. I would like to sort by transaction amount.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rewards {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String fileName = ("test.txt");
    FileReader fin = new FileReader("C:/Users/Jordan/Desktop/Project5Text.txt");
    Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    src.useDelimiter(":");

    Random rand = new Random();

    while (src.hasNext()) {
        String l = src.nextLine();
        if (!l.equals(""))
            lines.add(l);
    }
    String[] randomChoices = new String[1]; // Number of random choices

    for (int i = 0; i < randomChoices.length; i++) {
        String randomString = lines.get(1 + rand.nextInt(lines.size() - 1));
        randomChoices[i] = randomString;
    }

    for (String s : randomChoices)
        System.out.println("Random Winner for $20 gift card is:       " +s);

    String[] randomChoices1 = new String[1]; // Number of random choices

    for (int i = 0; i < randomChoices1.length; i++) {
        String randomString = lines.get(1 + rand.nextInt(lines.size() - 1));
        randomChoices1[i] = randomString;
    }

    for (String s : randomChoices1)
        System.out.println("Random Winner for $40 gift card is:       " +s);

    String[] randomChoices2 = new String[1]; // Number of random choices

    for (int i = 0; i < randomChoices2.length; i++) {
        String randomString = lines.get(1 + rand.nextInt(lines.size() - 1));
        randomChoices2[i] = randomString;
    }

    for (String s : randomChoices2)
        System.out.println("Random Winner for $60 gift card is:       " +s);

    String[] randomChoices3 = new String[1]; // Number of random choices

    for (int i = 0; i < randomChoices3.length; i++) {
        String randomString = lines.get(1 + rand.nextInt(lines.size() - 1));
        randomChoices3[i] = randomString;
    }

    for (String s : randomChoices3)
        System.out.println("Random Winner for $80 gift card is:       " +s);

    String[] randomChoices4 = new String[1]; // Number of random choices

    for (int i = 0; i < randomChoices4.length; i++) {
        String randomString = lines.get(1 + rand.nextInt(lines.size() - 1));
        randomChoices4[i] = randomString;
    }

    for (String s : randomChoices4)
        System.out.println("Random Winner for $100 gift card is:      " +s);

}
}
```

Here is some of the text file which I am using.

Order # Date First name Middle Initial Last name Address City State Zip Email Transaction Amount

1 8/26/2012 Kristina H Chung 947 Martin Ave. Muncie CA 46489 khchung@business.com $593

2 11/16/2012 Paige H Chen 15 MainWay Rd. Dallas HI 47281 phchen@business.com $516

3 11/10/2012 Sherri E Melton 808 Washington Way Brazil CA 47880 semelton@business.com $80

4 9/20/2012 Gretchen I Hill 56 Washington Dr. Atlanta FL 47215 gihill@business.com $989

5 3/11/2012 Karen U Puckett 652 Maplewood Ct. Brazil FL 46627 kupuckett@business.com $826

6 7/4/2012 Patrick O Song 679 MainWay Rd. Lafayette GA 47161 posong@business.com $652

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by creating a class that can represent a line in your file. In this class you will have fields for every column. Have this class implement the Comparable interface. This forces you to implement the compareTo() method.

When you've done this, you can simply create an ArrayList with this class and use the built in sort() method to sort it!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you first create a class that stores a row in a logical way:

```
class Transaction{
    String date;
    String name;
    String address;
    int amount;
    // etc...
}
```

Then you can store each transaction in a List and write a custom Comparator:

```
List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
...
Collections.sort(transactions, new Comparator<Transaction>(){
    public int compare(Transaction t1, Transaction t2){
        return Double.compare(t1.amount, t2.amount);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a simple (but not maximally efficient) solution, you can do:

```
    lines.sort(new Comparator<String>() {

        public double dollar(String line) {
            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            // take the last element and remove its first character ($)
            return Double.parseDouble(parts[parts.length - 1].substring(1));
        }
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            // swap o1 and o2 if you need to sort in the opposite order
            return Double.compare(dollar(o1), dollar(o2));
        }
    });
```